# how does setProgress() know which is the color of the progress that is to be grown in this code?

Tags: android, progress-bar

and when it calls setProgress(20) , how does it know that it is the green color will increase instead of the gray color?

```
  pb.setProgress(0);
  pb.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_progress));
  pb.setProgress(20);
```

Here is the **green_progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/greenStart"
                    android:centerColor="@color/greenMid"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="@color/greenEnd"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's thanks to the `@android:id/progress`, a special id which is known by `ProgressDialog` class. So, in `ProgressDialog`, the code know which shape it has to expand and which one it has to reduce, during the progression.